# Send emails from Email Service address?

Tags: email, email-template

I have an email service which parses responses if my customers send emails to the Salesforce generated email.

I want to know whether it is possible to send out emails from the Salesforce generated email address (using our email templates)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sending the email from Apex, you would want to set the Email service address as the reply-to address of your outgoing email.

If you want to set up the generated email service address as an Organization-Wide Email address you can use to send Email Alerts and other emails from, you need to follow these steps.

1. Add the line System.debug(email); to your handleInboundEmail
   method of your Email Service's Apex class.
2. Add the context user of
   the email service to Debug Log Monitored Users under Setup ->
   Monitor -> Logs -> Debug Logs
3. Add the generated Email Service
   email as an Organization-wide Address under Setup -> Administer ->
   Email Administration -> Organization-Wide Addresses
4. Go back to the Debug Logs page and find the log with the operation
   EmailToApexHandler.  Search for "Click this link to confirm this
   Organization-Wide Email Address: " and copy and paste the following
   link into another browser window, your email service address will
   now be verified.

Comment: If I were to create the email via Apex, is there a way I (or the user) could screen the email before its sent?

Comment: I don't believe there is a simple way.  Instead of sending the email from Apex you could insert the details into a custom object email queue, then have a page where you could preview those emails and a button to send the ones you want.

Comment: I wonder how difficult is it to create a VF page that shows selected fields on screen (doesnt have to be anything fancy) along with some related object fields and then place a button to send the email (via Apex).

Answer (score 1):

I have an email service that receives emails from users and parses them into the database.

We set up an [Organisation-Wide email address](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=orgwide_email.htm&language=en_US) whose address was the email service's inbound address. We have a workflow that fires an email out to the user, using the org-wide email as the "sender" address, and the user replies to the email.

Comment: The problem with this is that all emails sent by the system will be via the Email Service address. Im afraid I will receive responses which I do not want here.

Comment: "org wide email address" doesn't mean every email in the org must come from that address. It means you can manually send email from that address if you have permission, and the admin can set up any workflow email to come from that address. But all the other "from" addresses still work.